# Need `Hello World` example for Java Simple

Tags: java, xml

I'm struggling to understand Java [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php). Something about it looks very cool but I can't get my head around how to use it.

I can't find a 'Hello World' example that demonstrates how the bits-and-pieces fit together. I'm looking for something like this;

**Expected output**

```
<durr/>
```

**Demo.java**

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String str = new Foo();
       System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

**Foo.java**

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root
public class Foo{
    // Something
}
```

**Compile and run**

```
javac Demo.java Foo.java
java Demo
```

**Summary**

What is the simplest demo that can output `<durr/>` using Simple?

Comment: You should also check out JAXB:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-simple.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting directly from [simple's documentation](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#start):

> To serialize an instance of the above object a Persister is required. The persister object is then given an instance of the annotated object and an output result, which is a file in this example. Other output formats are possible with the persister object.

So basically, I would say your Demo class could be written in the following way:

```
import java.io.File;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer; 
import org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

   Foo foo = new Foo();
   Serializer serializer = new Persister(); 
   File result = new File("example.xml"); // XML OUTPUT WILL BE WRITTEN HERE
   serializer.write(foo, result);
}
```

Once again, based on the documentation I would say this will generate a `<foo/>` tag , because it's your class' name, to change it to `<duur/>` output you have to redefine the name in the root tag in your `Foo` class, like this:

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root(name="durr")
public class Foo{
 // Something
}
```

Comment: Thanks pabrantes. However I still can't get it to compile. I'm getting `incompatible types: Foo`. Should the line be changed to 'Foo foo = new Foo();` instead of `String str = new Foo();`?

Comment: @NigelAlderton: Sorry Nigel, it was a typo from a copy paste I was doing while replying to you. I've fixed the problem, it should work now.

Comment: It then said `unreported exception java.lang.Exception; must be caught or declared` for line `serializer.write(foo, result);`. Also, these imports are required; `java.io.File;org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer; org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister;`.  After adding a try/catch, and those imports, it works! Thanks for your help, I understand the basic idea now.

Comment: @NigelAlderton: Glad I could help you. The imports and try/catchs I usually leave out in explanations because that's the kind of thing the IDE takes care for you. If I've solved your problem consider accepting the answer in order to avoid this question to be wrongly listed as unanswered.

Comment: You should try Eclipse IDE: http://www.eclipse.org/ it helps you a lot in this kind of issues when you're starting.

Comment: Before I accept, for the benefit of anyone copying and pasting your answer, could you add the try/catch so it will compile.

Comment: @NigelAlderton: Nigel editted the answer, added the imports and instead of adding the try catch block just made the main throws Exception

Comment: Thanks again. Those `import ..` lines really help a Java newbie like me to connect all the pieces together.